# AWS Path based Routing: External Microservice

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes

**Situation**

I have multiple Micro-Services deployed. All micro-services should be made available under the domain `www.mycompany.com/[myservice]`.

Some of the micro-services are based on AWS, while other services are based on other technology.

**Question**

How can do I setup a routing in AWS to redirect

- `www.mycompany.com/blog` to an AWS Micro-Service
- `www.mycompany.com/support` to an external service hosted under the address `mycompany.zendesk.com`

How can I set such a routing mechanism up in AWS?

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge you can't setup this kind of routing using only Route 53. However there is a work around using API Gateway. If you can deploy all your microservices behind an API Gateway, you can configure routing as you had mentioned using the API Gateway custom domains option. I recently wrote an article on the usage of this feature, and link to that mentioned below.

[API management for microservices](https://codeburst.io/api-management-for-micro-services-micro-apis-5940f09fb638)